# Magento - Enable HTML links in error/custom messages

Tags: php, magento, tags, custom-errors, magento-1.9

I want to know if this is possible to enable HTML links in custom messages (ie: error messages).

Here is my example:
I've made an override for my needs of Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item/Item.php

Function checkQuoteItemQty :

```
if (!$this->checkQty($summaryQty) || !$this->checkQty($qty)) {
     //$message = Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The requested quantity for "%s" is not available.', $this->getProductName());
     $message = Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The requested quantity for "%s" is not available (max:%s).', $this->getProductName(), ($this->getQty() * 1));
     $cat_id = $this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
     if($cat_id){
         $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id[0])->getUrl();
         $message .= Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('You might be interested in <a href="%s">those products</a>.', $url);
      }
      $result->setHasError(true)
           ->setMessage($message)
           ->setQuoteMessage($message)
           ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
     return $result;
}
```

But the HTML link I created in $message is not clickable and considered as text (because of the translation I guess...).
Is it possible to change this behavior?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who would like to know, I had to override Mage_Core_Block_Messages, line 249 :

```
public function getGroupedHtml()
    {
        $types = array(
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::ERROR,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::WARNING,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::NOTICE,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::SUCCESS
        );
        $html = '';
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            if ( $messages = $this->getMessages($type) ) {
                if ( !$html ) {
                    $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . ' class="messages">';
                }
                $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . ' class="' . $type . '-msg">';
                $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';

                foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
                    $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
                    $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                    $html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->escapeHtml($message->getText()) : html_entity_decode($message->getText());
                    $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                    $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
                }
                $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
                $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
            }
        }
        if ( $html) {
            $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

Adding a html_entity_decode at this line :

```
$html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->escapeHtml($message->getText()) : html_entity_decode($message->getText());
```

Just let me know if you find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but in my case, by calling the obsolete method without "Message" solves the issue with the link.
Instead of using `addNoticeMessage`, I changed to `addNotice`, and the links appeared.
In my case:

```
$noticeMsg = __('You must be <a href="%1">logged in</a> or <a href="%2">registered</a> to purchase these products.',
                        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/login'),
                        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/create')
                    );
$this->_messageManager->addNotice($noticeMsg);
```